# Convergence of sequence with subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let ${a_n}$  be a bounded sequence such that any of its convergent proper subsequences converge to the same limit $l$. Prove that ${a_n}$ converges to $l$.

Any hints please?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $a_n$ does not converge to $l$. Then there is $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and an increasing sequence $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{n_k} - l| \gt \varepsilon$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. By Bolzano-Weierstrass $a_{n_k}$ has a convergent subsequence. Show that the limit of this subsequence cannot be $l$ and use this to conclude.

Answer (score 2):

The statement $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ means $$\forall r>0\;\exists n\;\forall m>n\;(|a_m- L|<r).$$

So $\neg (L=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n)$ means $$\exists r>0 \forall n\; \exists m,m'>n\;(|a_m-L|\geq r).$$ What does that $mean$? It means that there is an $r>0$  for which we can find

$m_1>1$ with $|L-a_{m_1}|>r,$ and

$m_2>1+m_1$ with $|L-a_{m_2}|>r$ and

$m_3>1+m_2$ with .....(etc).....

The set $S=\{m_2,,m_3,m_4,...\}$   excludes  $1+m_j$ for every $j\in \Bbb N.$  Consider the sequence $(a_k)_{k\in S}\;$.

Comment: @Janitha357. Obviously my mind was wandering. I have re-written it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_{n} $ is bounded the numbers $\liminf a_{n}, \limsup a_{n} $ exist (finitely). And there are subsequences of $a_{n} $ which converge to these numbers. But then every convergent subsequence of $a_{n} $ converges to the same limit $l$ it follows that these two numbers are same and equal to $l$ and hence the sequence $a_{n} $ converges to $l$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n \not \to l$ then there's an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for each $k$ we may find an $n_k \ge k$ such that $|a_{n_k} - l| \ge \epsilon$.  Clearly, we may also take $n_1 < n_2 < \dots$.  So $(a_n)$ has one nonconvergent subsequence, which is the contrapositive of your statement

Comment: That is not the contrapositive. We would need to find a convergent proper subsequence that does not converges to $l$ but to $r \not =l$ in order to show the contrapositive of the statement.

Answer (score -1):

It would be a good start assuming that the sequence does not converge to $l$.
Then try to find a proper subsequence that does not converge to $l$.